# Поведение блоков при адаптивной верске

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте! Прошу вашей помощи, не понимаю что не так...
есть такая верстка:

```
<div class="content">
 <div class="game"></div>
 <div class="game"></div>
 <div class="game"></div>
 <div class="game"></div>
 <div class="game"></div>
</div>

div.content {
padding: 0px 12px;
position:relative;
}

div.content div.game {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FCFCFC;
    border: 1px solid #666666;
    border-radius: 4px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 145px;
    margin: 0 0 18px;
    position: relative;
    width: 158px;
}
```

есть след. функция (нашел в инете, чуть изменил)

```
function smartColumns() {
var parentWrap = $("div.content").innerWidth();
var itemWidth = $("div.content div.game").outerWidth();
var colNum = (parentWrap / itemWidth); 
var colFixed = Math.floor(colNum * itemWidth);
var colMarg = (parentWrap - colFixed) / colNum; 
$("div.game").css({ 'margin-right' : colMarg}); 
$("div.content div.game:nth-child("+(colNum)+"n)").css("margin-right","0px").addClass("last");
}
```

При выполнение jquery ругается

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized
> expression: :nth-child Почему так
> происходит, подскажите пожалуйста как
> решить эту проблему

Comment: что такое lastItem ?

Comment: может у вас jQuery супердревняя (версия < 1.1.4)

Comment: стоит версия 1.11

Answer (score 1):

Если глобально у вас нигде не определена переменная lastItem, то она равна undefined, отсюда и проблема

[тык](http://jsfiddle.net/LCffZ/) и [тык](http://prntscr.com/3lx6np)

Нашлась ошибка: в переменной colNum содержалось не целое число, а 5.2959034852 или что-то подобное. В nth-child нужно передавать целое число, то есть простой parseInt(colNum) решает проблему http://jsfiddle.net/LCffZ/3/

Comment: нет, jquery не ругается если она undefined, хотя нет - в новых ругается. я просто тут на сайте в консоли проверял.

Comment: @eicto, обновил ответ. а в старых разве не ругается?

Comment: @Mit9l, посмотрите еще раз в свой код. а потом еще 20 раз пересмотрите. может вы еще что-то неправильно написали, а мы тут угадываем?

Comment: @Mit9l, css то выложите

Comment: в песочнице точно такую же ошибку кидает(

Comment: функция работает без проблем если в nth-child не вставлять переменную, а напрямую вписать цифру

Comment: извиняюсь...голова уже пухнет) исправил block на game)
проблема с colNum, но не могу понять как исправить и что с ней не так....(

Comment: @Mit9l, обновил ответ